# Easiest way to generate chart to an image server-side (to be embedded into PDF)

Tags: php, charts, server-side

I am using [Highcharts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highcharts) to generate nice-looking charts. I am trying get these charts embedded into a PDF, so I would need the process to generate the chart into an image done server side.

What is the simplest method ideally without any need for the command line?

Comment: And highsoft has a topic dedicated to that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net/) to generate graphs with PHP and save as an image:

Comment: Decided to use jpGraph in the end using the table formatter option which generates a graph from a HTML table.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate PDFs or any other office format (PDF, ODT...) including charts of any king with Docxpresso API. The API allow you to generate the document and the chart in one shot. You don´t need to generate the chart and then integrate it in the document. The API is free to use for non comercial use and you can install it in any server using PHP.
http://docxpresso.com/files/html52pdf.zip

Answer (score 0):

To use the amenadiel/jpgraph package in a Laravel application and display a graph on a blade page, you can follow these steps:

you can also use this merge request for all changes: https://github.com/saber13812002/bot-generator-bale-telegram-laravel-10/pull/28/files

Install the amenadiel/jpgraph package using Composer by running the following command in your terminal:

```
composer require amenadiel/jpgraph
```

Create a new route in your Laravel application to display the graph. Open the routes/web.php file and add the following route definition:

```
Route::get('/graph', function () {
    // TODO: Generate graph
    return view('graph');
});
```

This route will return a blade view called graph.

In the route callback function, generate the graph using the amenadiel/jpgraph package. Here's an example code snippet to create a simple bar graph:

create controller:

```
php artisan make:controller ChartController
```

add this line to api.php in route folder in laravel

```
Route::get('/chart', [ChartController::class, 'chart']);
```

create method in ChartController named chart: put this code there

```
use Amenadiel\JpGraph\Graph\Graph;
use Amenadiel\JpGraph\Plot\BarPlot;
use Amenadiel\JpGraph\Plot\Plot;

$data = [30, 50, 80, 60, 70];  // Sample data

$graph = new Graph(400, 300);
$graph->SetScale('textlin');
$graph->SetMargin(50, 30, 50, 50);

$plot = new BarPlot($data);
$plot->SetFillColor('#3182bd');
$plot->SetWidth(0.5);

$graph->Add($plot);

$graph->Stroke();
```

This code creates a new Graph object with a size of 400x300 pixels and sets the scale to textlin. It then creates a BarPlot object with the sample data and customizes its appearance. The plot is added to the graph using the Add method. Finally, the Stroke method is called to output the graph as a PNG image.

Save the generated graph to a file or output it directly to the browser. To output the graph directly to the browser, you can capture the output of the Stroke method using output buffering and return it as a response:

use this code after last code in chart method in ChartController like this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

ob_start();
$graph->Stroke();
$image_data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return new Response($image_data, 200, [    'Content-Type' => 'image/png',]);
```

This code captures the output of the Stroke method using output buffering and stores it in the $image_data variable. It then sends a Response object with the image data, a status code of 200, and a Content-Type header of image/png.

Create a new blade view called graph.blade.php in the resources/views directory and add an image tag to display the graph:

```
<img src="{{ url('/api/graph') }}" alt="Graph">
```

This code creates an image tag that points to the /graph route that we defined earlier. When the page is rendered, the browser will request the graph image from the server and display it in the page.

That's it! You should now be able to see a simple bar graph on the /graph page of your Laravel application. You can customize the graph further by modifying the code that generates it.